# Add res/menu folder on created project

Tags: android, menu, toolbar, android-resources

I already have a project created, but I need the res/menu folder to add a toolbar to the layout, I've been searching and none of them worked, can you help me find the problem please?

[image: Project]

This is the style error:

[image: Error Style]

Layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background_menu"
  tools:context="com.example.caca_a_frase.Menu" >  
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.
  -->

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:rotation="350"
        android:src="@drawable/titulo_menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoJogar"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/botao_jogar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoOpcoes"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botao_opcoes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoSair"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/botao_sair" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/botao_info"
        android:text="" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

  </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Right click on your res folder in project structure and create a new directory named 'menu'. and create the menu xml inside it.

Comment: Already did that and it didn't work

Comment: Why 'didn't work' ? Please explain your problem.

Comment: It says that styles are missing

Comment: @OliverCarneiro can u post a screenshot with that error msg?

Comment: @OliverCarneiro can u post your layout xml as well

Comment: @OliverCarneiro in the first screenshot u have choosen "FullScreen" theme. Can u Change that to different theme say _AppCompat_ and try once

Comment: Can't change it. I choose AppCompat and it doesn't make any changes, it continues in Fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on res folder select Android resource directory

[image]

Select Resource type menu and click ok

[image]

Comment: I already did that and it didn't work for me, it says that styles are missing.

Answer (score 0):

please rename **activity_menu** to **menu**